# how to check a checkbox outside of table on selecting rows of that table with checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a table with selectable rows with checkboxes. and I have another checkbox named Select all outside of that table function which I want to be checked on checking any of the row in table. how do I do that in Nextjs typescript ?

here is the table and 'select all' checkbox outside on top right.[image]

I tried this:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);

 class SelectTableComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props: {} | Readonly<{}>) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        List: files,
        MasterChecked: false,
        SelectedList: [],
      };
    }

    // Select/ UnSelect Table rows
    onMasterCheck(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
      let tempList = this.state.List;
      tempList.map((file: { selected: any; }) => (file.selected = e.target.checked));

      //Update State
      this.setState({
        MasterChecked: e.target.checked,
        List: tempList,
        SelectedList: this.state.List.filter((e: { selected: any; }) => e.selected),
      });
    }


    // Update List Item's state and Master Checkbox State
    onItemCheck(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, file: { name: any; selected: any; }) {
      let tempList = this.state.List;
      tempList.map((files: any) => {
        if (file.name === file.name) {
          file.selected = e.target.checked;
        }
        return file;

      }
      );

      // To Control Master Checkbox State
      const totalItems = this.state.List.length;
      const totalCheckedItems = tempList.filter((e: { selected: any; }) => e.selected).length;

      // Update State
      this.setState({
        MasterChecked: totalItems === totalCheckedItems,
        List: tempList,
        SelectedList: this.state.List.filter((e: { selected: any; }) => e.selected),
      });
    }

    // Event to get selected rows(Optional)
    getSelectedRows() {
      this.setState({
        SelectedList: this.state.List.filter((e: { selected: any; }) => e.selected),
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 tablediv">
              <>
                <table className="table imagetable">
                  <thead style={{ backgroundColor: '#f3f8ff' }}>
                    <tr role="row">
                      <th colSpan={1} role="columnheader" className="tableheadings">
                        <input
                          type="checkbox"
                          className="form-check-input"
                          checked={this.state.MasterChecked}
                          id="mastercheck"
                          onClick={(e) => this.onMasterCheck(e)}
                        />
                      </th>
                      <th scope="col">Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">File Type</th>
                      <th scope="col">File Size (kb)</th>
                      <th scope="col">View</th>
                      <th scope="col">Last Modified</th>
                      <th scope="col">Details</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <>
                      {files.map((file: any) => (
                        <tr key={file.name}
                          className={file.selected ? "selected" : ""}

                        >
                          <th scope="row">
                            <input
                              type="checkbox"
                              checked={file.selected}
                              className="form-check-input"
                              id="rowcheck{user.id}"
                              onChange={(e) => this.onItemCheck(e, file)}
                            // onClick={() => setSelected(!selected)}
                            // (e) => this.onItemCheck(e, file)
                            />
                          </th>
                          <td className="tablecontent">{file.name}</td>
                          <td className="tablecontent">{file.contentType}</td>
                          <td className="tablecontent">{file.fileSize}</td>
                          <td
                            className="tablecontent">
                            <Link href={file.url}
                              style={{ color: '#000000', textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                              View Image
                            </Link>
                          </td>
                          <td className="tablecontent">{file.updateDate}</td>
                          <td className="tablecontent"

                            style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}>
                            View Details
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <label
                  className="btn btn-light"
                  onClick={() => this.getSelectedRows()}
                >
                  No. of Selected Items : {this.state.SelectedList.length}

                </label>
                {/* {setAbc(this.state.SelectedList.length)} */}
                {
                  this.state.SelectedList.length > 0
                    ?
                    // setSelected('true')

                    // setSelected(true)
                    setAbc(this.state.SelectedList.length)

                    :
                    // setSelected('false')


                    setSelected(false)


                }
              </>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }






{
                        selected === (true)
                          ?
                          <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input checkbox" checked />
                          :
                          <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input checkbox" />
                      }
                      &nbsp;&nbsp; Select All
```

`

Comment: What do you mean by "enter image description here"? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve this question.